# Express a real number (or a vector) in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

Probably this is the silliest question that could be made. However, that's a question:

If a complex number could be written in matrix form, it is legit to write a real number $n$ too as $\begin{matrix}n & 0\\ 0 & n\end{matrix}$ ?

Moreover, could a vector $[n, m]$ be thought and written like $\begin{matrix}n & 0\\ 0 & m\end{matrix}$ ?

Comment: Usually, we work with $n$ as $nI=\begin{bmatrix}n&0\\0&n\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: That's true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can look for a matrix equivalent of the imaginary unit $i$ :
$$
M^2 = -I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, which is the one on $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.
This can be 
$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
A complex number $z=x+iy$ could be
\begin{align}
z &= x I + y M \\
&= 
x 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
+
y
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
x & y \\
-y & x
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
And complex multiplication would be
\begin{align}
z_1\, z_2 &=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
x_1 & y_1\\
-y_1 & x_1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
x_2 & y_2 \\
-y_2 & x_2
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2 & x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1 \\
-(x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1) & x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&= (x_1 x_2 - y_1 y_2) + i (x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_1)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. The whole question depends on that word: "equivalent". If an antisymmetric matrix could be viewed as equivalent to the imaginary unit, could the scalar matrix be thought as equivalent to a real number?

Comment: The real numbers map to multiples of the identiity matrix $I$.